# change a flutter widget from the tree

Tags: flutter

I'm making an application that displays an image from a URL when the user clicks a button the URL change and the image do the same. Using the flutter Image widget there is no problem, but when I try to use flutter_zoomable_image
from perlatus when I try to change the URL the image does not change. This is the code of the function of the widget:

```
[...]
_updatePhoto() {
  _photo.setName(surl.getCurrentMount());
  _photo.setUrl(surl.getCurrentUrl());
  setState(() {
    img = _photo.getImage();
  });
}
[...]
 body: new SizedBox.expand(
    key: new Key('photo'),
    child: img,
  ),
[...]
```

And this is the code of the photo that is updating the image:

```
ZoomableImage img;
void _setImage(){
  //img = new Image(image:new CachedNetworkImageProvider(url));
  img = new ZoomableImage(
    new CachedNetworkImageProvider(url),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white
  );
}
ZoomableImage getImage() => img;
```

The code is in two distinct files. If you need more just ask.

Thanks in advance!